# Machine Learning Supervised Clustering on a Field

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, amazon-sagemaker, google-cloud-automl, machine-learning-model

I'm trying to build a model on labeled data that can cluster on a specific field.

Example data:

[image]

The field I want to cluster on is class_id. I want to be able to give the model (class_id, date, class_time) and get an estimated time in minutes that a student stays in my class for a specific date and time. I want to cluster by class_id because each class is different in its own way. Is there a model or way that can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not looking for clustering.

Instead, what you ask for is trivial SQL: `GROUP BY class_id`.

It classes are indeed that different, then you'll likely want to learn a separate regression for each class, after partitioning.